# Segmentation fault Gecode 6.2.0 when running examples

Tags: c++, ubuntu-20.04, gecode

I am getting a segmentation fault when I attempt to run `examples/<some example>` after my installation of Gecode. I configured before `make` with

```
./configure -with-gmp-include=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -with-gmp-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -with-mpfr-include=/usr/include/ -with-mpfr-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

and after an installation of `qt5-default`. My platform is Ubuntu 20.04. `make` and `make install` seemed to be fine (no errors) but when I try to run an example (any example in Gecode's examples folder) I get, if using `money` example:

```
$ ./examples/money
SEND+MORE=MONEY
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is going to need more code for context. There's a lot of things that can result in a segmentation fault, and most are in your code.

Comment: @tadman: This is not my code. This is Gecode's code.

Comment: Then you'll have to debug their code. The normal procedure is to file a bug report with the author(s).

Comment: @tadman: I think this is more to do with an installation/configuration issue than a code issue. I am pretty sure their code is fine.

Comment: My advice: File a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

A restart after installation solved this for me.

Comment: Happy to delete question and answer if people think that would be more appropriate.